# How to install and use PouchDB in react native?

Tags: react-native, pouchdb

I am looking for a simple NoSQL database to be used locally (without sync with server) in a react native app and I decided to give PouchDB a try.

I am wondering which of the following  2 packages I should use :

```
> npm install pouchdb    
> npm install pouchdb-react-native
```

pouchdb-react-native seems a better choice but its not active, not documented, without tutorials.

Is it possible to install pouchdb-react-native  and use the js pouchdb documentation and tutorials?

Comment: Any update? I'm currently giving a try to PouchDB (CouchDB derivation) and I'm also finding a lot of deprecated tools and errors. The other main no-sql alternative is MongoDB Realm.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not the answer you're looking for, but, I've tried to use puochdb for RN, and I found is deprecated (despite the warning given last November after 2 years of inactivity)..and I tried to used it, but is painful to get that work.

I recommended you to give a chance to [WatermelonDB (https://github.com/Nozbe/WatermelonDB)](https://github.com/Nozbe/WatermelonDB), which is up to date, and works pretty fine to persist complex data structures.

Comment: Thanks of the suggestion. But WatermelonDB documentation snippets are not written in Typescript. Do you use Typescript with WaterlemonDB?  Have you seen some tutorials written in typescript?

Comment: And also, were you able to use Expo Go with WatermelonDb ?

Comment: is a little pity, but it has some TS support.

https://github.com/Nozbe/WatermelonDB/tree/master/examples/typescript

About Expo Go, unfortunately, I only use expo for experiments, and teaching if necessary. I don't like it for real life projects because I don't like to have a black box inside my apps.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I missed it when I had a first look at the doc. One more question if you don't mind. I am new on react native and I'd like to keep at least expo bare workflow.  The only see I saw on the web is this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@morrowdigital/watermelondb-expo-plugin.  But it has much explanation.  Have you ever used it? Is it necessary? Or Does a plain "yarn add expo" enough to add expo in the doc example? Thanks again.

Comment: due to I'm not using expo cli, I just installed and see what's happening, and as far as I understood, your plugins section should be like follow:

    "plugins": [
      "@morrowdigital/watermelondb-expo-plugin",
      [
        "expo-build-properties",
        {
          "android": {
            "compileSdkVersion": 31,
            "targetSdkVersion": 31,
            "buildToolsVersion": "31.0.0"
          },
          "ios": {
            "deploymentTarget": "13.0"
          }
        }
      ]
    ]

Comment: However, watermelon installation requires some native changes, and I'm not sure we can do that using Expo Go :-( .

Comment: Not Expo go but Expo development client. But this is not enough documentation and support for that so I think I will search for another DB. Thanks anyway.